# jQuery animate always happens fast

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My code:

```
    $('.btn').animate(
        {
            fontSize: "3em"
        }, 
        10000);
```

.btn is class of button. No matter what animation duration I set, it always happens very fast (text becomes bigger very fast).

I really can't see an error, can you? Thanks.

**edit:** Magic happens in this world... I just tried to rewrite it and it works now... Wow

Comment: could you make an example on jsfiddle.net ? because it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/BQkdf/

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MDEuh/

Comment: Works fine for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrLeD/)

Comment: What browser is this failing in... this JSFiddle of your code is working in the latest (dev) version of Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/wf9Yf/

Comment: jsfiddle's gonna hate SO for flooding :P -- this is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/NdLcF/1/

Comment: Strange, it works in fiddle :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure jQuery.fx.off is not set to true

> All jQuery effects, including .animate(), can be turned off globally by setting jQuery.fx.off = true, which effectively sets the duration to 0. For more information, see [jQuery.fx.off](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/).

Comment: That could be. Or same error I did a couple days ago, when I `.fadeOut()`'d a `<div>` then `.hide()`'d its parent..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it outside your context? That exact code alone works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NdLcF/1/

Can you post some more of the JS context (mainly, other stuff changing styles around there)?